# React Js Error : Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I am just trying to append elements (Dynamic elements) but when I want to access these elements I can access only input elements but not the Div which I have given ref, Please help thanks In advance.

Error I am getting:

Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  CardHeader,
  FormGroup,
  Input,
  Label,
  Col,
} from 'reactstrap';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { policyValidationRule } from "../../../../services/policyValidationRuleService";
import './CreateRule.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const url = window.location.href.split("/");
var id = url[url.length - 1];

const RuleForElements = props => {
  return (
    <div className="ruleForDiv">
      <FormGroup>
        <div className="row">
          <Label htmlFor={'n_PrValidationCodeMasters_FK_' + props.count} className="col-md-3">Select Rule For:</Label>
          <Input type="select" className="col-md-6 n_PrValidationCodeMasters_FK" name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][n_PrValidationCodeMasters_FK]'} id={'n_PrValidationCodeMasters_FK_' + props.count}
            ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['n_PrValidationCodeMasters_FK_' + props.count] = ref} onChange={props.thisRefrence.onChangeRuleFor} required>
            <option value="">Select Rule For</option>
            {props.ruleForOptions}
          </Input>
        </div>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <div className="row">
          <Label htmlFor={'s_FormulaExpression_' + props.count} className="col-md-3">Select Formula Expression:</Label>
          <Input type="select" className="col-md-6 s_FormulaExpression" id={'s_FormulaExpression_' + props.count} name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][s_FormulaExpression]'} required
            ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['s_FormulaExpression_' + props.count] = ref}
          >
            <option value="">Select Formula Expression</option>
            {props.mathMaticSymbols}
          </Input>
        </div>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup id={'dropDownTr_' + props.count} ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['dropDownTr_' + props.count] = ref} style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <div className="row">
          <Label htmlFor={'s_CompareValueDD_' + props.count} className="col-md-3">Value:</Label>
          <Input type="select" className="col-md-6" id={'s_CompareValueDD_' + props.count} name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][s_CompareValueDD]'} required
            ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['s_CompareValueDD_' + props.count] = ref}
          >
          </Input>
        </div>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup id={'dropDownTrTo_' + props.count} ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['dropDownTrTo_' + props.count] = ref} style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <div className="row">
          <Label htmlFor={'s_CompareValueBetweenDD_' + props.count} className="col-md-3">Value To:</Label>
          <Input type="select" className="col-md-6" id={'s_CompareValueBetweenDD_' + props.count} id={'s_CompareValueBetweenDD_' + props.count} name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][s_CompareValueBetweenDD]'} required
            ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['s_CompareValueBetweenDD_' + props.count] = ref}
          >
          </Input>
        </div>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup id={'textTr_' + props.count} ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.div['textTr_' + props.count] = ref} style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <div className="row">
          <Label htmlFor={'s_CompareValueText_' + props.count} className="col-md-3">Value:</Label>
          <Input type="text" className="col-md-6" id={'s_CompareValueText_' + props.count} name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][s_CompareValueText]'} required
            ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['s_CompareValueText_' + props.count] = ref}
          />
        </div>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup id={'textTrTo_' + props.count} ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['textTrTo_' + props.count] = ref} style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <div className="row">
          <Label htmlFor={'s_CompareValueBetweenText_' + props.count} className="col-md-3">Value To:</Label>
          <Input type="text" className="col-md-6" id={'s_CompareValueBetweenText_' + props.count} name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][s_CompareValueBetweenText]'} required
            ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['s_CompareValueBetweenText_' + props.count] = ref}
          />
        </div>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup id={'RadioTr_' + props.count} ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['RadioTr_' + props.count] = ref} row style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <Col md="3">
          <Label>Select Value:</Label>
        </Col>
        <Col md="9">
          <FormGroup check inline>
            <Input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id={'RadioYes_' + props.count} name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][s_CompareValueRadio]'} value="Yes"
              ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['RadioYes_' + props.count] = ref}
            />
            <Label className="form-check-label" check htmlFor={'RadioYes_' + props.count}>Yes</Label>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup check inline>
            <Input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id={'RadioNo_' + props.count} name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][s_CompareValueRadio]'} value="No"
              ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['RadioNo_' + props.count] = ref}
            />
            <Label className="form-check-label" check htmlFor={'RadioNo_' + props.count}>No</Label>
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <div className="row">
          <Label htmlFor={'s_ConditionBetween_' + props.count} className="col-md-3">Select Condition Between:</Label>
          <Input type="select" className="col-md-6 s_ConditionBetween" id={'s_ConditionBetween_' + props.count} name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][s_ConditionBetween]'} required
            ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['s_ConditionBetween_' + props.count] = ref}
          >
            <option value="AND">And</option>
            <option value="OR">Or</option>
          </Input>
        </div>
      </FormGroup>
      <Input type="hidden" id={'element_to_display_' + props.count} name={'element_to_display_[' + props.count + ']'}
        ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['element_to_display_' + props.count] = ref}
      />
      <Input type="hidden" id={'s_CompareValueDB_' + props.count} name={'s_CompareValueDB_[' + props.count + ']'}
        ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['s_CompareValueDB_' + props.count] = ref}
      />
      <Input type="hidden" id={'s_CompareValueBetweenDB_' + props.count} name={'s_CompareValueBetweenDB_[' + props.count + ']'}
        ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['s_CompareValueBetweenDB_' + props.count] = ref}
      />
      <Input type="hidden" id={'n_PrValidationRuleDetail_PK_' + props.count} name={'TbPrvalidationruledetail[' + props.count + '][n_PrValidationRuleDetail_PK]'}
        ref={(ref) => props.thisRefrence.input['n_PrValidationRuleDetail_PK_' + props.count] = ref}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Elements are appending from RuleForElements component.
Both Components are present in same file.

```
class PolicyValidationRuleCreate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.apiService = new policyValidationRule();
    this.state = {
      isFetching: false,
      formOptions: [],
      products: [],
      rulesApplyOn: [],
      ruleForOptions: [],
      mathMaticSymbols: [],
      editRuleData: [],
      ruleForElements: [],
    };

    this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this);
    this.onChangeRuleFor = this.onChangeRuleFor.bind(this);
    this.input = [];
    this.div = [];

    if (isNaN(id) == true) {
      id = '';
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderMyData();
    }
  }

  renderMyData() {
    //fetch data of dropdowns etc.
    this.props.dispatch(this.apiService.fetchPolicyValidationFormOptions(id))
      .then((resp) => {
        this.setState({
          isFetching: true,
        });

        let productsData = this.props.formOptions.data.n_Product_FKData;
        let productsOptions = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < productsData.length; i++) {
          productsOptions.push(<option key={productsData[i].n_ProductId_PK} value={productsData[i].n_ProductId_PK}>{productsData[i].s_ProductName}</option>);
        }

        let rulesData = this.props.formOptions.data.s_RuleApplyOnData.POLICYRULEAPPLYON;
        let rulesOptions = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < rulesData.length; i++) {
          rulesOptions.push(<option key={rulesData[i].s_AppCodeName} value={rulesData[i].s_AppCodeName}>{rulesData[i].s_AppCodeNameForDisplay}</option>);
        }

        this.setState({
          formOptions: this.props.formOptions.data,
          products: productsOptions,
          rulesApplyOn: rulesOptions,
          isFetching: false,
          editRuleData: this.props.formOptions.data.n_PrValidationRuleMaster_PKData,
        });

      });

    this.props.dispatch(this.apiService.fetchPolicyRuleForOptions())
      .then((resp) => {
        this.setState({
          isFetching: true,
        });

        let rulesForOptionsArr = this.props.ruleForOptions.data.ValidationCodeDD;
        let rulesForOptions = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < rulesForOptionsArr.length; i++) {
          rulesForOptions.push(<option key={rulesForOptionsArr[i].n_PrValidationCodeMaster_PK} value={rulesForOptionsArr[i].n_PrValidationCodeMaster_PK}>{rulesForOptionsArr[i].s_FieldScreenLabel}</option>);
        }

        let numberSignArr = this.props.ruleForOptions.data.numberSign;
        let numberSign = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < numberSignArr.length; i++) {
          var part = numberSignArr[i].split(":");
          numberSign.push(<option key={part[0]} value={part[0]}>{part[1]}</option>);
        }

        this.setState({
          ruleForOptions: rulesForOptions,
          mathMaticSymbols: numberSign,
          isFetching: false,
        });
      });
  }

  //add rule for row
  addRow() {
    var count = 0;
    count = document.querySelectorAll('#appendRow .n_PrValidationCodeMasters_FK').length;
    this.setState({
      ruleForElements: [this.state.ruleForElements, <RuleForElements key={parseInt(count)}
        ruleForOptions={this.state.ruleForOptions}
        mathMaticSymbols={this.state.mathMaticSymbols}
        count={parseInt(count)}
        thisRefrence={this}
      />]
    })
    document.getElementById('TableRowIncrementNo').value = (count + 1);
console.log(this.input);
  }


  render() {
    const containerStyle = {
      zIndex: 1999
    };

    if (this.state.products.length == 0) {
      return <div className="animated fadeIn pt-1 text-center">Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="animated fadeIn col-md-12">
            <ToastContainer position="top-right" autoClose={5000} style={containerStyle} />
            <Card>
              <form id="ruleForm">
                <CardHeader id="formHeader">Create Rule</CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_RuleCode" className="col-md-3">Rule Code:</Label>
                      <Input type="text" className="col-md-7 text-uppercase" id="s_RuleCode" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_RuleCode'] = ref} name="s_RuleCode" placeholder="Enter Rule Code" required />
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_Description" className="col-md-3">Description Of Rule:</Label>
                      <Input type="textarea" className="col-md-7" id="s_Description" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_Description'] = ref} name="s_Description" required />
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="n_Product_FK" className="col-md-3">Select Product:</Label>
                      <Input type="select" className="col-md-7" id="n_Product_FK" ref={(ref) => this.input['n_Product_FK'] = ref} name="n_Product_FK" required>
                        <option value="">Select Product</option>
                        {this.state.products}
                      </Input>
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_ScreenErrorMsg" className="col-md-3">Screen Error Msg:</Label>
                      <Input type="text" className="col-md-7" id="s_ScreenErrorMsg" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_ScreenErrorMsg'] = ref} name="s_ScreenErrorMsg" required />
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_RuleApplyOn" className="col-md-3">Rule Apply On:</Label>
                      <Input type="select" className="col-md-7" id="s_RuleApplyOn" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_RuleApplyOn'] = ref} name="s_RuleApplyOn" required>
                        <option value="">Select Rule Apply On</option>
                        {this.state.rulesApplyOn}
                      </Input>
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup className="add_row">
                    <Button type="button" className="btn-sm pull-right" color="success" onClick={this.addRow}>Add Row</Button>
                    <Input type="hidden" id="TableRowIncrementNo" name="TableRowIncrementNo" ref={(ref) => this.input['TableRowIncrementNo'] = ref} value="0"></Input>
                  </FormGroup>
                  {this.state.ruleForElements}
                  <FormGroup>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_CanRate" className="col-md-3">Can Rate Policy:</Label>
                      <Input type="select" className="col-md-7" id="s_CanRate" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_CanRate'] = ref} name="s_CanRate" required>
                        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                        <option value="N">NO</option>
                      </Input>
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_CanPrintQuote" className="col-md-3">Can Print Quote:</Label>
                      <Input type="select" className="col-md-7" id="s_CanPrintQuote" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_CanPrintQuote'] = ref} name="s_CanPrintQuote" required>
                        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                        <option value="N">NO</option>
                      </Input>
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_CanPrintQuote" className="col-md-3">Can Print Application:</Label>
                      <Input type="select" className="col-md-7" id="s_CanPrintApp" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_CanPrintApp'] = ref} name="s_CanPrintApp" required>
                        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                        <option value="N">NO</option>
                      </Input>
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_CanBindApp" className="col-md-3">Can Bind Application:</Label>
                      <Input type="select" className="col-md-7" id="s_CanBindApp" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_CanBindApp'] = ref} name="s_CanBindApp" required>
                        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                        <option value="N">NO</option>
                      </Input>
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_CanUnBoundApp" className="col-md-3">Can Submit Un Bound Application:</Label>
                      <Input type="select" className="col-md-7" id="s_CanUnBoundApp" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_CanUnBoundApp'] = ref} name="s_CanUnBoundApp" required>
                        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                        <option value="N">NO</option>
                      </Input>
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_CanIssue" className="col-md-3">Can Issue Policy:</Label>
                      <Input type="select" className="col-md-7" id="s_CanIssue" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_CanIssue'] = ref} name="s_CanIssue" required>
                        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                        <option value="N">NO</option>
                      </Input>
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="d_EffectiveDateFrom" className="col-md-3">Rule Start Dt.</Label>
                      <Input type="date" className="col-md-7" id="d_EffectiveDateFrom" ref={(ref) => this.input['d_EffectiveDateFrom'] = ref} name="d_EffectiveDateFrom" placeholder="Rule Start Dt." required />
                      <span className="text-danger" id="d_EffectiveDateFrom_Error"></span>
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="d_EffectiveDateTo" className="col-md-3">Rule End Dt.</Label>
                      <Input type="date" className="col-md-7" id="d_EffectiveDateTo" ref={(ref) => this.input['d_EffectiveDateTo'] = ref} name="d_EffectiveDateTo" placeholder="Rule End Dt." required />
                    </div>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                      <Label htmlFor="s_RuleStatus" className="col-md-3">Rule Status:</Label>
                      <Input type="select" className="col-md-7" id="s_RuleStatus" ref={(ref) => this.input['s_RuleStatus'] = ref} name="s_RuleStatus" required>
                        <option value="ACTIVE">Active</option>
                        <option value="INACTIVE">InActive</option>
                      </Input>
                    </div>
                    <Input type="hidden" id="n_PrValidationRuleMaster_PK" ref={(ref) => this.input['n_PrValidationRuleMaster_PK'] = ref} name="n_PrValidationRuleMaster_PK" />
                  </FormGroup>
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter>
                  <div className="text-right">
                    <Button type="submit" id="ruleFormSubmit" ref={(ref) => this.input['ruleFormSubmit'] = ref} color="primary" onClick={this.submit}><i className="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit</Button>
                    <Button type="reset" color="danger"><i className="fa fa-ban"></i> Reset</Button>
                  </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </form>
            </Card>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  formOptions: state.Administration.fetchPolicyValidationFormOptions,
  ruleForOptions: state.Administration.fetchPolicyRuleForOptions,
  ruleForData: state.Administration.fetchPolicyRuleForData,
  saveResponse: state.Administration.savePolicyRuleValidation,
  innerRules: state.Administration.fetchInnerPolicyRule
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PolicyValidationRuleCreate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it the issue in my code is I am trying to add ref on react elements like  which is not allowed so I added ref on normal HTML elements and it worked.